# Even more variables in once cell on excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Someone very kindly answered this question for me the other week but now I need to make it even more specific:

*How can I have a cell display a one of 3 different predetermined figures based on the contents of 3 other cells? I need it to understand that depending on how many of a certain thing is performed in one day that an expected target of something else should be added to a total. For example, if an employee takes over 10 calls it is assumed that they are on the phone all day and should therefore be able to respond to a KPI of 50 emails. If they take less than 10 calls it is assumed they are on other functions and would not be expected to respond to 50 emails. I want the spreadsheet to calculate their KPI over a month based on their functions each day.
The cell that contains the formula is D62. I want D62 to display 200 if the number in T3 is greater than 10 and 0 if it is less than 10. However, the other variable is that if the number in T3 is less than 10 but the number in BP3 is greater than 10 I need D62 to display 50.
`=IF(T3>10,200,0,IF(BP3>10,50,0)) This is where I got to`*

As I said, someone guided me to the right formula here. The problem I have now is that I want to introduce a further range where if the contents of T3 is between 30 and 50 D62 would return 50. I have tried the following formula:

```
=IF(T3>30,200,IF(T3<50,50,IF(BP3>10,50,0)))
```

This however is returning 50 when the contents of T3 is 0. Can I make the second IF rule a range rather than just below a number?

Comment: You've described conflicting requirements.  You specify values depending on whether T3 is > or < 10, and it is supposed to be `0` if T3 is <10.  Then you introduce BP3, which you want to affect cases where T3 is <10.  It can't be both `0` and something else.  Similarly, if T3 is >10, it can't be both 200 and some other value if it is between 30 and 50.  You need to clearly define what you want the rules to be.  Also, IF tests have the structure: IF(condition, result if true, result if false).  (cont'd)

Comment: That covers all possible cases because the condition has to be either true or false.  You can't have IF(condition, result if true, result if false, some other result).  If you want to nest IFs, either the true result or false result becomes the next IF test.

Comment: You need to clearly define consistent, logical rules to help create the correct formula. fixer1234 and randomhero are on point.

Comment: Thank you for your help on this everyone, I did think it might be the case that I was trying to ask too much of it. I will have a fiddle with some AND statements and see what I can get out of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is expected behavior given the if statement you have written. (0 is less than 50).

You might need to include an AND statement:

`=IF(AND(A1<75,A1>50), "Pass", "Fail")`

Or you may need an OR statement as well:

`=IF(OR(A1>75,B1<75), "Pass", "Fail")`